# React-Testing-Library, Jest ,and MSW testing Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3001

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing a component's submit button and the test passes but I would really like this `ECONNREFUSED` error to go away and understand why this is happening. The line of code that throws the error in my test is `await userEvent.click(submitBtn)`. If I comment out that line of code, the error goes away.

I read [this](https://EConnectionRefused%20means%20there%20is%20still%20an%20API%20call%20which%20is%20being%20executed.%20I%20don%27t%20know%20how%20you%20spy%20on%20yours.%20The%20reason%20it%27s%20not%20there%20when%20you%20comment%20out%20your%20waitFor%20is%20because%20your%20test%20exits%20before%20you%20execute%20it.%20You%20probably%20do%20get%20an%20act%20warning%20in%20that%20case%20if%20you%20set%20state%20after%20the%20call.) StackOverflow and it seems to be a similar issue. The answer states:

> EConnectionRefused means there is still an API call that is being executed. I don't know how you spy on yours. The reason it's not there when you comment out your `waitFor` is that your test exits before you execute it. You probably do get an act warning in that case if you set state after the call.

I am not familiar with spying on API calls and I do not get any `act` warnings. My guess is it has to do with this test being async, but I tried testing without it. So, instead of using `await` in the line that was throwing an error I used the `waitFor` method from React-Testing-Library. The issue I had with this is that the button never gets clicked.

The specific line of code I used with the `waitFor` method was `waitFor(() => userEvent.click(submitBtn))`.

Another cause of the problem may be how I am calling my render function with the submit jest function with these two lines of code in my test:

```
const submit = jest.fn()
renderWritingField(userData, unirepData, postData, submit, type, page)
```

Here is the test:

```
// import 'whatwg-fetch'
import { screen, render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import UnirepContext from '../../src/context/Unirep'
import UserContext from '../../src/context/User'
import PostContext from '../../src/context/Post'
import WritingField from '../components/writingField/writingField'


// abstracted render function
function renderWritingField(
    userData,
    unirepData,
    postData,
    type,
    page,
    submit
) {
    return render(
        <UserContext.Provider value={userData}>
            <UnirepContext.Provider value={unirepData}>
                <PostContext.Provider value={postData}>
                    <WritingField
                        type={type}
                        submit={submit}
                        submitBtnName={'subbtn'}
                        onClick={jest.fn()}
                    />
                </PostContext.Provider>
            </UnirepContext.Provider>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}


test('should throw error text if user does not enter any value for title or content and clicks submit button', async () => {
    const page = '/user'
    const type = 0
    const unirepData = {
        unirepConfig: {
            commentReptation: 30,
        },
    }
    const postData = {
        commentsById: {
            commentId: {
                id: 'commentId',
                content: 'string',
                post_time: '00',
                reputation: 30,
                epoch_key: 'epoch_key test',
            },
        },
        setDraft: jest.fn(),
        postDraft: {
            title: 'Post Draft title',
            content: 'Post Draft content',
        },
        commentDraft: {
            title: 'Comment Draft title',
            content: 'Comment Draft content',
        },
    }

    const userData = {
        userState: true,
        currentEpochKeys: ['user epoch_key test'],
    }

    const submit = jest.fn()
    renderWritingField(userData, unirepData, postData, submit, type, page)
    const submitBtn = screen.getByText(/subbtn/i)

    expect(submitBtn).toBeInTheDocument()

    await userEvent.click(submitBtn)

    expect(
        screen.getByText(/please input either title or content./i)
    ).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Component that is being tested:

```
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import 'react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'

import UnirepContext from '../../context/Unirep'
import UserContext from '../../context/User'
import PostContext from '../../context/Post'

import HelpWidget from '../helpWidget/helpWidget'
import { DataType, InfoType } from '../../constants'
import { shortenEpochKey } from '../../utils'

type Props = {
    type: DataType
    submit: (
        title: string,
        content: string,
        epkNonce: number,
        reputation: number
    ) => void
    submitBtnName: string
    onClick: (event: any) => void
}

const WritingField = (props: Props) => {
    const unirepConfig = useContext(UnirepContext)
    const user = useContext(UserContext)
    const postContext = useContext(PostContext)

    const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>('')
    const [content, setContent] = useState<string>('')
    const [epkNonce, setEpkNonce] = useState<number>(0)
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState<string>('')

    const defaultRep =
        props.type === DataType.Post
            ? unirepConfig.postReputation
            : unirepConfig.commentReputation
    const [reputation, setReputation] = useState(defaultRep)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.type === DataType.Post && postContext.postDraft) {
            setTitle(postContext.postDraft.title)
            setContent(postContext.postDraft.content)
        } else if (
            props.type === DataType.Comment &&
            postContext.commentDraft
        ) {
            setContent(postContext.commentDraft.content)
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        setErrorMsg('')
    }, [title, content, reputation, epkNonce])

    const onClickField = (event: any) => {
        props.onClick(event)
    }

    const handleTitleInput = (event: any) => {
        setTitle(event.target.value)
        postContext.setDraft(props.type, event.target.value, content)
    }

    const handleContentInput = (event: any) => {
        setContent(event.target.value)
        postContext.setDraft(props.type, title, event.target.value)
    }

    const handleRepInput = (event: any) => {
        setReputation(+event.target.value)
    }

    const submit = () => {
        if (!user.userState) {
            setErrorMsg('Please sign up or sign in')
        } else {
            if (title.length === 0 && content.length === 0) {
                setErrorMsg('Please input either title or content.')
            } else {
                props.submit(title, content, epkNonce, reputation)
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="writing-field" onClick={onClickField}>
            {props.type === DataType.Post ? (
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Give an eye-catching title"
                    onChange={handleTitleInput}
                    value={title}
                />
            ) : (
                <div></div>
            )}
            {props.type === DataType.Post ? (
                <textarea onChange={handleContentInput} value={content} />
            ) : (
                <textarea
                    autoFocus
                    onChange={handleContentInput}
                    value={content}
                />
            )}
            <div className="info-row">
                <div className="element">
                    <div className="name">
                        Post as <HelpWidget type={InfoType.epk4Post} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="epks">
                        {!user.userState ? (
                            <div>somethings wrong...</div>
                        ) : (
                            user.currentEpochKeys.map((epk, i) => (
                                <div
                                    className={
                                        i === epkNonce ? 'epk chosen' : 'epk'
                                    }
                                    onClick={() => setEpkNonce(i)}
                                    key={epk}
                                >
                                    {shortenEpochKey(epk)}
                                </div>
                            ))
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="element">
                    <div className="name">
                        My Rep display <HelpWidget type={InfoType.rep} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="rep-chooser">
                        <input
                            type="range"
                            min={defaultRep}
                            max={
                                user.userState ? user.netReputation : defaultRep
                            }
                            onChange={handleRepInput}
                            value={reputation}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={reputation}
                            onChange={handleRepInput}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="submit-btn" onClick={submit}>
                {props.submitBtnName}
            </div>
            {errorMsg.length > 0 ? (
                <div className="error">{errorMsg}</div>
            ) : (
                <div></div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default observer(WritingField)
```

The error in the console:

```
Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3001
        at Object.dispatchError (/Users/anthonymadia/code/work/Unirep-Social/packages/frontend/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:63:19)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/anthonymadia/code/work/Unirep-Social/packages/frontend/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
        at Request.emit (node:events:402:35)
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/anthonymadia/code/work/Unirep-Social/packages/frontend/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:121:14)
        at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
        at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
        at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
      type: 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?